# What are these routing styles called in a web application?

Tags: php, routes, naming, front-controller, fastroute

**What do you call routing that maps one URL directly to a file?**

Example:

`http://localhost/directory/file.php` => `/var/www/apache/htdocs/directory/file.php`

**What do you call routing like one on https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute?**

Example:

`http://localhost/directory/file` => request actually goes to a single `index.php`  file, which then loads routing files or tables and loads appropriate class as defined in the routing table.

Comment: "What do you call routing that maps one URL directly to a file?" **Outdated.**

Comment: I'm curious, when did it become outdated?  Do you ever see it come up in new projects still?

Comment: Several years, at minimum. I can't think of the last time I saw a project by a reputable developer that didn't use a framework and router of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What do you call routing that maps one URL directly to a file?

I would call that no routing. Or maybe direct routing? I've never heard anybody use a term specifically for it.

> What do you call routing like one on https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute?

That's (typically) the [front controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) pattern.

Comment: thanks.  I now see that no-routing pattern is sometimes called page controller, aka each page acts as its own controller

Comment: Ehhh... I wouldn't quite say that. A page controller implies a controller per **logical** page. With a direct routing approach, there are not necessarily any logical pages, and if there are, there do not necessarily have one controller per.